# Disable foreign key constraints

Tags: laravel

I want to disable foreign key constraint on a relationship because I have a problem after:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can disable foreign key constraints in your migration file.

```
Schema::disableForeignKeyConstraints();
```

Ref: [Laravel migrations nice way of disabling foreign key checks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298639/laravel-migrations-nice-way-of-disabling-foreign-key-checks)

Comment: This answer was chosen as the best answer and also upvoted twice. So, could someone explain me why do you want to disable FK constraints (which is already a terrible way to work with migrations) and then enable those in each migration class just to run `refresh` command? How is this dirty fix with a lot of additional work better than just running `fresh` instead of `refresh`?

Comment: Although this comment was posted in 2017: I don't use it in migrations, where I'd agree it's bad practice. I used it in a DB Seeder during local development and testing. I needed to truncate a table during seeding which was the target of foreign keys of other tables. I think there it absolutely makes sense.

Answer (score 8):

In 5.5 you can just use the [`fresh`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations#running-migrations) command:

```
php artisan migrate:fresh
```

> The `migrate:fresh` command will drop all tables from the database and then execute the migrate command