# Laravel, pivot table conflicts with many-to-many relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, uuid

Hey guys so I'm using spatie binary uuid package and I had few doubts
Things done so far:
User.php Migration:

```php
 public function up()
  {
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->uuid('uuid');
        $table->primary('uuid');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
 }
```

Role migration just have basic field called "name" with timestamps

Pivot table: role_user

```php
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->uuid('user_uuid');

    });
}
```

I know this is terribly wrong and I don't know what to do, I'm trying to save the Role model via this call

```php
$uuid = '478d7068-ae64-11e8-a665-2c600cf6267b';
$model = User::withUuid($uuid)->first();
$model->roles()->save(new Role(['name' => 'Admin']));
```

it doesn't work, where am I going wrong? I think it has something to do with role_user migration

User.php

```php
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
}
```

Comment: the pivot table is not actually referencing any of the related tables

Comment: and please add the `roles` relation code from the `User` model

Comment: How will I reference uuid to that pivot table? also I added the roles relation.

Comment: How is it not working? Are you getting an error? Also, what version of Laravel are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should edit your relation to this

```
return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_uuid','role_id');
```

if you say about your error we better can help you

Answer (score 1):

try this, pivot migration:

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('role_user', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('role_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
        $table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->uuid('user_uuid');
       $table->foreign('user_uuid')->references('uuid')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

roles relation:

```
public function roles(){
  return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class,'role_user','user_uuid','role_id');
}
```

please let me know if it didn't work

Comment: Your migration seems to be not working, I added foreign value given by you and it gives me   Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced ina foreign key constraint

Comment: Nevermind it works but somehow that error comes up when I seed the UsersTableSeeder

Comment: this is not a migration error, maybe you are trying to delete the relation/user/role somewhere in the code

Comment: ok disable foreign key check in the seed file, check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34298639/laravel-migrations-nice-way-of-disabling-foreign-key-checks

Comment: in the seed file add this: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;');` and once done deleting enable it: `\Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::statement('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;');`

Comment: Yes I'll definitely do this.. Thanks man I was first checking that link and in it the method deleteForiegnKeyConstrain wasn't working I'll try this though