# Managing orphaned MySQL rows when performing Laravel migration

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys, migration

I am attempting to add a migration that properly sets FK's on all tables that needs them. The previous developer did not use FKs. Without a doubt there will be several orphaned records where the foreign key does not exists and will result a foreign key constraint failure when performing the migration. Is there a way in Laravel to check to make sure the foreign key exists before applying the constraint, or set null if not exists? In the example below, I already know the table `records_awards` has records where the `user_id` column record does not exist anymore. How can I set `user_id` to null before applying the constraint?

```php
Schema::table('records_awards', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->change()->constrained('users')->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('award_id')->nullable()->change()->constrained('awards')->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('document_id')->nullable()->change()->constrained('documents')->nullOnDelete();
    $table->foreignId('author_id')->nullable()->change()->constrained('users')->nullOnDelete();
});
```

Comment: Does the [info here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34298639/7644018) possibly help?

Comment: @PaulT. interesting. Thanks I’ll look into it.